# Building an NSstring out of an NSMutableArray

Tags: nsstring, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nslog

My eyes hurt from hours of trying to figure this one - and i have looked for an answer for quite a while on-line (it will be embarrassing to tell how much...).
all i am trying to do is to enumerate using a for-in loop on anExpression which is a NSMutableArray that holds NSNumbers and NSStrings.
my NSLog print for the variable ans returns an empty string.
What am i doing wrong?

```
  NSString *ans = @"";
    for (id obj in anExpression)
    {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
            [ans stringByAppendingString:(NSString *)obj];
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
            [ans stringByAppendingString:(NSString *)[obj stringValue]];

        NSLog(@"String so far: %@ ", ans);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean

```
ans = [ans stringByAppendingString:(NSString *)obj];
```

not just

```
[ans stringByAppendingString:(NSString *)obj];
```

NSStrings are immutable -- you can't append to them. `-stringByAppendingString:` returns a **new** string (which you could then assign to `ans`).

Alternatively, you might use an `NSMutableString` and the `-appendString:` method.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, sorry for the bad coding format, posting it again ...

```
NSString *ans = @"";
for (id obj in anExpression)
{
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        [ans stringByAppendingString:(NSString *)obj];
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
        [ans stringByAppendingString:(NSString *)[obj stringValue]];

    NSLog(@"String so far: %@ ", ans);
}
[ans autorelease];
NSLog(@"final string is: %@ ", ans);

return ans;
```

Comment: The `[ans autorelease];` is incorrect -- `ans` was never `alloc`-ed, and the object returned from `stringByAppendingString:` should not be released.

Comment: OK, thank you. as for the main problem i encounter - not being able to fill the NSString with the objects i have in the array - do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

the method `stringByAppendingString:` returns a *new* string made by appending the given string to the receiver.

so you want `ans = [ans stringByAppendingString:obj];`